# Why are my c:\NativeImage\mscorsvw.exe\ and C:\Default\mscorsvw.exe folders so large (each are between 25 and 35 gigs). Can i delete them?

Tags: .net, sql, space

The files that appear to be the largest within these folders have titles like:

**(690MB)**

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.HTM
```

**(673MB)**

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.HTM     

etc...
```

Can i safely remove the contents of these folders and save myself over 90 gigs of space?

Please provide some sort of evidence/proof that your answer will not wreck my system.

Thanks!

Comment: Those are the NGen native cache folders. I'm not sure why they're placed at that location on your system, since by default they should be in `%WINDIR%\assembly`... You could run ngen /display and see what you get.

Comment: @marceln Using ngen /display just shows me all the files in those folders (at least from what it appears). The real question is can i safely delete these files? Also, something i just thought of, will uninstalling and reinstalling .net possibly fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Fusion Logging has been turned on with a custom location. To turn this off run fuslogvw.exe from a visual studio command prompt and click the settings button then click disable.